# Speed up adding items to listbox (code behind or xaml binding?)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, json.net

I'm displaying a list of images in a listbox, and each image has a title underneath it. The data is a JSON array with JObject's for each child in the array.

The listbox item is a stackpanel, and the image and text is inserted into the stack panel, which is then inserted into the listbox as an item.

The only problem is that it is slow with lots of data (40 or more items).

I have heard that XAML data binding is much faster, but am having no luck getting anything on the screen.

Is XAML binding going to speed this up so it's usable? Ideally i'd like it to be instant, or "pop in" style where each item is added as it is available, without locking up the program. The data is taken from local JSON files and local images.

If it can be done just as good in the code behind, then great. But I can't seem to improve the speed. Moving it over to a thread also didn't make any marginal difference.

Here is how I am adding the items via the code behind:

```cs
    // Loop through the data
foreach (dynamic item in this.data.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
{
    // Create the image for this item
    this.images[item.i] = new Image
    {
        Width = 278,
        Height = 178,
    };

    // If the image for this item exists
    if (File.Exists(item.value["Image"].ToString()))
    {
        // The path to this image
        string imageFilePath = item.value["Image"].ToString();
        // Set the image source
        this.images[item.i].Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageFilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }

    // Create a stack panel to store our item
    StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel
    {
        Width = 288,
        Height = 215,
    };

    // Create the items text
    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
    textBlock.text = item.value["Text"].ToString();

    // Add the Image to the stack panel
    stackPanel.Children.Add(this.images[item.i]);
    // Add the text to the stack panel
    stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);

    // Add the stackpanel to the list
    this.Items.Add(stackPanel);
}
```

The Window's XAML:

```xml
    <Window x:Class="MyProject.Windows.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window" Width="800" Height="600">

    <Grid>
        <!-- The list box -->
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the XAML for the ListBox that I tried to bind. It results in nothing appearing on the screen.

EDIT: If I move the below code behind into a method, and call that method somewhere in my code it does result in my images/text appearing on the screen. It just does not do it initially, why? It is also just as slow as the code behind version.

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding testList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="20" />
            </VirtualizingStackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And the code behind for the XAML binding

```cs
// List to store our data
private List<Item> testList { get; set; }

public MyClass()
{
    // Initialise the test list
    this.testList = new List<Item>();
    // Loop through the data
    foreach (dynamic item in this.data.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
    {
        Item item = item.value.ToObject<Item>();
        this.testList.Add(item);
    }

    this.ItemsSource = this.testList;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is `ToObject` doing? What type is value before calling `ToObject`?

Comment: ToObject is a JSON.Net method which can be called on JObjects to convert them to a specific type. In this case an item, which is a class with two members Image and Text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create your controls in code behind. Instead, use `Binding` and `ItemTemplate` of the `ListBox` and `DataTemplate`. I try to explain the best approach:

Create a class with these two properties:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    string _imageFilePath;
    public string ImageFilePath { get { return _imageFilePath; } set { _imageFilePath = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ImageFilePath"); } }

    string _text;
    public string Text { get { return _text; } set { _text = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Text"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    } 
}
```

Your most important job should be to populate an `ObservableCollection<Model>`, by looping through your data. Lets put this collection in the following class:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
         //populate the Models here 
    }

    ObservableCollection<Model> _models;
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Models { get { return _models; } set { _models = value; } }

}
```

Use

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageFilePath }"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="20" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

for which the DataContext is set propertly:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

This should work.

Comment: You don't really need to specify the `DataContext` for `ListBox`.  Especially since `DataContext={Binding}` is just binding the `DataContext` to itself.

Comment: Thank you, I see some differences in your code compared to the code I attempted. I'll give this a whirl and report back

Comment: I'm going to accept this as it answers the question, but am going to ask a new question that is more focused on one specific aspect that i'm still having trouble with. Thanks